# Quickbooks web API - Pulling data from quickbooks

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I would like to be able to pull data from an existing online QB setup that I have access to, specifically all customers data that are sub accounts of a specific parent account. I would then like to add the data to a html table. Is this possible and if so where do I start? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming question, or a question of how to use the Quickbooks website?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Programming

Comment: @codevalue  Did you do any research at all on this topic? Google and StackOverflow searches return an absolute TON of results if you just do a little research and searching on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible

Yes.

> where do I start?

If I was you... I would start by searching. This question gets answered over and over and over again on StackOverflow, and there's tons of Google results too.

But... here's an overview:

- Go grab some open-source code from GitHub: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php
- Follow the quick-start guide linked to from that GitHub page: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start
- The quick-start guide basically walks you through creating an app registration with Intuit, setting up some configuration, etc. All of the real details are documented on the [QuickBooks developer](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting) website in lots of detail.

Look in the docs/ directory of the above QuickBooks PHP open-source code. There's lot of examples of querying QuickBooks Online for data. Specifically, you're probably going to want some code that looks like this:

```
$CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();
$customers = $CustomerService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Customer MAXRESULTS 25");
foreach ($customers as $Customer)
{
    print('Customer Id=' . $Customer->getId() . ' is named: ' . $Customer->getFullyQualifiedName() . '<br>');
}
```